# Why is this chrome extensions manifest allow to read and write on all sites?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my chrome extension manifest

```
{
  "name": "demoallow",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "demo allow perissions to read and write",
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidepanel.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["sidePanel"]
}
```

the only permissions that are requested is sidepanel. however chrome gives much more:

> Site access This extension can read and change your data on sites. You
> can control which sites the extension can access.

My question is: how do i change the manifest so chrome does not give the mentioned read write permissions, but still included in the side panel?

Comment: It's a bug. Try fully removing the extension, restart the browser to clear the state, install it again.

Comment: i just did that, but got the same results. @wOxxOm

Comment: Well, it's a persistent bug in the UI, it just says false info.

Comment: should report it to google? how do i do that?